# Could not instantiate Seam component: org.jboss.seam.bpm.jbpm becausl of pageflow resource not found: checkout.jpdl.xml

Tags: jboss5.x, jbpm

Currently I am working on the JBPM 3.3 with seam and using Jboss 5.1 as application server.
I am getting the below exception though I have checkout.jpdl.xml exist.

The below is my components.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/components"
xmlns:core="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/core" xmlns:persistence="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/persistence"
xmlns:bpm="http://jboss.com/products/seam/bpm" xmlns:security="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/security"
xmlns:theme="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/theme" xmlns:cache="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/cache"
xmlns:web="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/web" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/core http://jboss.org/schema/seam/core-2.3.xsd
                   http://jboss.org/schema/seam/persistence http://jboss.org/schema/seam/persistence-2.3.xsd
                   http://jboss.org/schema/seam/bpm http://jboss.org/schema/seam/bpm-2.3.xsd
                   http://jboss.org/schema/seam/security http://jboss.org/schema/seam/security-2.3.xsd
                   http://jboss.org/schema/seam/theme http://jboss.org/schema/seam/theme-2.3.xsd
                   http://jboss.org/schema/seam/cache http://jboss.org/schema/seam/cache-2.3.xsd
                   http://jboss.org/schema/seam/web http://jboss.org/schema/seam/web-2.3.xsd
                   http://jboss.org/schema/seam/components http://jboss.org/schema/seam/components-2.3.xsd">
<!-- <core:init jndi-pattern="booking/#{ejbName}/local" debug="true" /> -->
<core:init jndi-pattern="java:app/booking.jar/#{ejbName}"
    debug="true" distributable="false" />
<core:manager conversation-timeout="120000"
    concurrent-request-timeout="500" conversation-id-parameter="cid" />

<security:identity authenticate-method="#{login.login}" />
<component class="org.jboss.seam.transaction.EjbSynchronizations"
    jndi-name="java:app/jboss-seam/EjbSynchronizations" />
<component class="org.jboss.seam.async.TimerServiceDispatcher"
    jndi-name="java:app/jboss-seam/TimerServiceDispatcher" />
<bpm:jbpm>
    <bpm:pageflow-definitions>
    <value>checkout.jpdl.xml</value>
    <!-- <name>newuser</name> -->
    <!-- <value></value> -->
    </bpm:pageflow-definitions>
</bpm:jbpm>
```

and the below is the server log which is showing .jpdl file does not exist.

```
   14:50:12,429 INFO  [ServletContextListener] Welcome to Seam 2.2.0.GA
14:50:14,401 WARN  [Component] Component class should be serializable: authenticator
14:50:14,833 WARN  [PersistentPermissionResolver] no permission store available - please install a PermissionStore with the name 'org.jboss.seam.security.jpaPermissionStore' if persistent permissions are required.
14:50:14,909 INFO  [StaleObjectLogConfigurer] stale object exceptions will be hidden from logging
14:50:14,921 ERROR [[/booking]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: org.jboss.seam.bpm.jbpm
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2144)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:278)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endInitialization(ServletLifecycle.java:116)
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:740)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pageflow resource not found: checkout.jpdl.xml
    at org.jboss.seam.bpm.Jbpm.getPageflowDefinitionFromResource(Jbpm.java:161)
    at org.jboss.seam.bpm.Jbpm.installPageflowDefinitions(Jbpm.java:278)
    at org.jboss.seam.bpm.Jbpm.startup(Jbpm.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2249)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callCreateMethod(Component.java:2172)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2132)
    ... 75 more
14:50:14,923 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
14:50:14,923 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/booking] startup failed due to previous errors
14:50:14,938 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/booking state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/Migration_Workspace/Jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a524k6t-qwkxos-ic5ziz2v-1-ic5zkf57-a0/app.war/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:331)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
14:50:15,081 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=jboss-seam.jar,name=EjbSynchronizations,service=EJB3
14:50:15,094 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: org.jboss.seam.transaction.EjbSynchronizations ejbName: EjbSynchronizations
14:50:15,126 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=jboss-seam.jar,name=TimerServiceDispatcher,service=EJB3
14:50:15,152 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: org.jboss.seam.async.TimerServiceDispatcher ejbName: TimerServiceDispatcher
14:50:15,200 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=app.jar,name=BookingListAction,service=EJB3
14:50:15,206 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: BookingListAction ejbName: BookingListAction
14:50:15,228 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=app.jar,name=ChangePasswordAction,service=EJB3
14:50:15,232 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: ChangePasswordAction ejbName: ChangePasswordAction
14:50:15,253 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=app.jar,name=HotelBookingAction,service=EJB3
14:50:15,258 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: HotelBookingAction ejbName: HotelBookingAction
14:50:15,302 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=app.jar,name=LoginAction,service=EJB3
14:50:15,306 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: LoginAction ejbName: LoginAction
14:50:15,322 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=app.jar,name=RegisterAction,service=EJB3
14:50:15,326 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: RegisterAction ejbName: RegisterAction
14:50:15,342 INFO  [PersistenceUnitDeployment] Stopping persistence unit persistence.unit:unitName=booking.ear/app.jar#booking-seam
14:50:15,342 INFO  [SessionFactoryImpl] closing
14:50:15,342 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Unbinding factory from JNDI name: persistence.unit:unitName=booking.ear/app.jar#booking-seam
14:50:15,342 INFO  [NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}
14:50:15,342 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Unbound factory from JNDI name: persistence.unit:unitName=booking.ear/app.jar#booking-seam
14:50:15,355 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=booking.ear,name=EjbSynchronizations,service=EJB3
14:50:15,359 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: org.jboss.seam.transaction.EjbSynchronizations ejbName: EjbSynchronizations
14:50:15,376 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Stopping jboss.j2ee:ear=booking.ear,jar=booking.ear,name=TimerServiceDispatcher,service=EJB3
14:50:15,380 INFO  [EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB: org.jboss.seam.async.TimerServiceDispatcher ejbName: TimerServiceDispatcher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WildFly 8.2.0 by default gives hibernate 4.3 jars and trying to run JBPM 3.3 on hibernate 4.3. But JBPM 3.3 will not support hibernate 4.3. To resolve this we need to bundle the Hibernate 3.x jars >3.5x and as per the WildFly documentation

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide